# Creating a Bin for NaN values

Tags: matlab, nan, binning

I am trying to do some data analysis  and the idea is to use the `autobinning` command to create optimal bins, calculate the WOE (Weight of evidence) value for each bin and then replace the original values that belong to each bin with the respective WOE value. So below is what I do:

```
CreSC = creditscorecard(Data_Table ,'IDVar','CustID','GoodLabel',0);
scAB = autobinning(CreSC,'Algorithm','Monotone');
DataTransformed = bindata(scAB,t_Data,'OutputType','WOE');
```

The problem is that the above procedure does not consider the `NaN` values that are in the DATA and automatically excludes them.

My aim is to create a separate bin only for the `NaN` values and force the `autobinning` command to consider the `NaN` values.

Does anyone have a reasonable solution ?

Comment: Not applicable with newer matlab versions. Obsolete!

Answer (score 1):

Find all NaN values.

Pick a value that is not present inside your data.

Replace all NaN values by this value.

Run your binning, and map this value yourself to NaN in the end.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried this already. This way does not seem to work because the intervals of the bins are affected with the assigned value on the NaNs. Again, my goal is to create a bin with ONLY NaNs!